# Add an external/affiliate product to cart on WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Working on a client's website which uses External products that link to an enquiry form further down on the page. I would like to add this product to the cart when the form is submitted.

I have tried just adding "?add-to-cart=[product-id]&quantity=1" to the end of the URL when the submit button is clicked, where [product-id] corresponds to the current product's ID but it just pops up with a message saying

"Sorry, this product cannot be purchased."

I just need the name of the product to be added to the cart with no price attached.

As clarification, the user will not be charged. It will send the order confirmation to the admin and customer, total price and payment will be arranged offline.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: You want external/affiliate product from your website to be added to cart ? The way this type works its not possible without alot modifications. You can instead create order on submiting the form including this product i think. Never tested.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.